# CMapStringToString crashes while looking up for a key in different class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I create a CMapStringToString, say, in class A in Project(exe). I populate this map in class A but I need to send this map to class B in different Project(dll). It just so happens that whenever I try looking up for keys, I get an exception.

However, when I try looking up for the key in same class A, it works just fine.

```
//This class is in exe project.
void A::AMethod
{
  CMapStringToString my_map;              //This map is a member variable.
  my_map.SetAt(_T("Key"), _T("value"));
  B obj;                                  //This class is in a DLL            
  obj.BsMethod(&my_map);                  //This will crash later in class B. 
                                          //And apparently I cannot pass by value
                                          //(which is bad but yeah).
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  CString sKey, sValue;
  sKey.Format(_T("key"), sValue);
  CMapStringToString* pTempCheckMap;
  pTempCheckMap = &my_map;
  pTempCheckMap->LookUp(sKey, sValue); //This works fine and I get the value.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 };


 //This class is in different project, a DLL and the method is exported.
 void B::BMethod(CMapStringToString* myPopulatedMap)
 {
  if(NULL != myPopulatedMap)              //Map has valid reference and is populated.
  {
   CString sKey, sVal;
   sTemp.Format(_T("key"));
   myPopulatedMap->LookUp((LPCTSTR)sKey, sVal);  //Crashes here.
  }
}
```

I tried debugging further into LookUp the crash was occurring at Map_ss.cpp in GetAssocAt method. Following is the snippet.

```
CMapStringToString::CAssoc*
CMapStringToString::GetAssocAt(LPCTSTR key, UINT& nHash) const
// find association (or return NULL) 
{
  nHash = HashKey(key) % m_nHashTableSize;

  if (m_pHashTable == NULL)
        return NULL;

  // see if it exists
  CAssoc* pAssoc;
  for (pAssoc = m_pHashTable[nHash]; pAssoc != NULL; pAssoc = pAssoc->pNext)
  {
        if (pAssoc->key == key)
              return pAssoc;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Any insight in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with explanation of the error. Also show how you are sharing data with DLL. Is there multi-threading?

Comment: Your map in class A is defined in the AMethod. Outside of that method it will be dead. Surely you need to define it as a member of the class rather than the method? In addition it is not clear how you are invoking class B with the instance of the variable from class A.

Comment: [`AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState( ))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a12b49ky.aspx) may help